# Programs become unresponsive

Tags: firefox

I have changed from Mint 13 to Ubuntu, complete fresh install. However I regularly get programs becoming unresponsive after switching between screens or work places.

Example before i was using firefox have 2 pop up screens(no junk ones) bank login and an ebay chat, switching between them and then firefox faded to grey and I had to force close as it become unresponsive.

Ubuntu is very nice to use, but I never had these problems using mint 13.

Is this common, are there any fixes coming??

Answer (score 0):

You mention bank login and firefox... so I suspect this is `java` related. And Java is one of the few differences between Ubuntu and Mint. Also, please notice that Unity 3D is far more resource-consuming than cinnamon/mate

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, New to the linux Distros, Is there any thing I can do, settings etc to help? I really like Ubuntu, problem is not that bad when you compare all the issues with windows 7!! Haven't had a Blue Screen Of Death since using linux, which used to be a common thing!! Cheers

Comment: Does this happen only with firefox, or other apps as well?